# Ruby outputting to the same line as the previous output

Tags: ruby, scripting

I am writing a Ruby script to generate a CSV file. 
My understanding is that each line in a CSV file is a row in a table.

Right now my script generates something looks like this

```
Vancouver, Calgary,
Routes1,
Routes2,
Routes3,
Vancouver, Toronto
etc,
etc,
etc
```

but I need it to make it look like this to import it to a DB

```
Vancouver, Calgary, Routes1, Routes2, Routes3
Vancouver, Toronto, etc etc etc..
```

My script works by looking up Vancouver and Calgary from raw data that contains the locations of the routes in different files. Then the script goes to those files to look for actual routes. Each time it finds a route (eg. Route1), the script outputs it using "puts" method. 
The problem is that every output is on a new line.

Is there a way to suppress the new line command when using "puts" command?

Comment: Have you looked at using http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/ ? you could build an array and use to_csv on it

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, use `print var` instead; `puts` automatically appends a new line, `print` doesn't.

Comment: For new line use print "\n"

Comment: Or for a new line, just `puts ''`